# Can't merge in-memory PDF files with iText7

Tags: c#, html, pdf, merge, itext7

I am trying to convert some HTML files into PDF files and then merge those PDFs together.
I am using **iText7** and I have tried some approaches:

**First approach**:

```
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Utils;

[...]

public static byte[] GeneratePdfFromHtmlFiles(params string[] htmlSources)
{
    using (var docStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var docWriter = new PdfWriter(docStream))
    using (var doc = new PdfDocument(docWriter))
    {
        var merger = new PdfMerger(doc);
        foreach (var html in htmlSources)
        {
            using (var pageStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var pageWriter = new PdfWriter(pageStream))
            using (var page = new PdfDocument(pageWriter))
            {
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, page, new ConverterProperties());
                doc.AddNewPage(); // I don't even know if this is needed
                var numberOfPages = page.GetNumberOfPages();
                merger.Merge(page, 1, numberOfPages);
            }
        }
        return docStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

In this first approach, the line `merger.Merge(page, 1, numberOfPages);` throws a `NullReferenceException`. I suspect it's because `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, page, new ConverterProperties());` closes the `PdfDocument` associated with `page`. I have tried to add `page.SetCloseWriter(false);` right before converting, but without success.

**Second approach:**

```
using iText.Html2pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Kernel.Utils;

[...]

public static byte[] GeneratePdfFromHtmlFiles(params string[] htmlSources)
{
    using (var docStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var docWriter = new PdfWriter(docStream))
    using (var doc = new PdfDocument(docWriter))
    {
        var merger = new PdfMerger(doc);
        foreach (var html in htmlSources)
        {
            using (var pageStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var pageWriter = new PdfWriter(pageStream))
            using (var page = new PdfDocument(pageWriter))
            {
                page.SetCloseWriter(false);
                HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, page, new ConverterProperties());
                using (var newPage = new PdfDocument(pageWriter))
                {
                    var numberOfPages = newPage.GetNumberOfPages();
                    merger.Merge(newPage, 1, numberOfPages);
                }
            }
        }
        return docStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This second approach is pretty much like the first, but I try to create a new `PdfDocument` from `pageWriter` that I left open with `page.SetCloseWriter(false);`. However, the line `var numberOfPages = newPage.GetNumberOfPages();` returns 0, which is followed by an error at `merger.Merge(newPage, 1, numberOfPages);` when it executes.

Again, what I am trying to achieve is to **merge some HTML pages into one PDF file**. I really would like to use an in-memory solution and I think my problem boils down to the fact that `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf` closes the `PdfDocument`. Perhaps I am taking a naive approach, and I'm stuck with those problems without being able to figure out a solution.

**Update**

I used @ShaneDems approach and it seems to work fine. I was afraid it would join all my pages weirdly, but with some tweaking on my CSS, my final PDF file has one HTML per page, which is what I wanted:

```
var html = string.Join(string.Empty, htmlSources);
using (var docStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var docWriter = new PdfWriter(docStream))
using (var doc = new PdfDocument(docWriter))
{
    HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, doc, new ConverterProperties());
    return docStream.ToArray();
}
```

And for my CSS tweaks, I used:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        margin: 0
    }

    .footer {
         (...)
         page-break-after:always;
    }
</style>
```

I wonder, however, a case where you *don't* have access to the HTMLs you want to convert or you can't inject CSS, it would be interesting to find a solution using multiple PDF pages and merging them.

Still, I achieved my goal so, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd merge the html files together first and then convert into one pdf.

Just append all of the strings in your htmlSources array to some new string, then create the pdf with that new string.

Comment: I used your approach and it worked (I updated the answer). Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Comment: There is one issue with that approach.  I had a template I'd fill in, but the HTML was very position based.  I appended each page, but when it rendered all the pages started at the top due to the absolute positioning.  In this case you need to convert to PDF then merge the pdf data into the main document.